# Reading Protobuf message data field-by-field

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

For my Java-based application, I need to convert Protobuf messages to Avro records on the fly. The schemas of the messages and records are **unknown at compile time**, but are known at runtime. The Avro side of this flow is done, but I am struggling with the Protobuf side. How can I take a Protobuf message, as a byte array, and turn it into something that can be read field-by-field using a DescriptorProto for the message type? I have spent quite some time getting up to speed on the Protobuf API and looking for relevant examples, but my use case does not appear to be a very common one.

Here is what I can do so far:

- load a FileDescriptorSet from disk which describes the message types I will encounter on the wire, and select the appropriate DescriptorProto for a particular message type
- step through the fields of the DescriptorProto, so that I know in principle how to interpret the data of a particular message
- construct test messages using generated classes, producing byte arrays which are representative of what I can expect on the wire

What I can not yet do:

- given the byte array, and given a field in the DescriptorProto, **select the message's value for that field**

I have tried merging the byte array into various builders which are based on the DescriptorProto, but they do not seem to give me what I need. I am also unable to reproduce the original byte array from these builders. There is obviously some conceptual gap I need to overcome.

**Edit**: here are some additional details on what I am attempting to do. The code has been simplified for brevity.

Load one or more `DescriptorProto` from disk:

```java
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/path/to/mydescriptors.pb");
FileDescriptorSet set = FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(is);
FileDescriptorProto geoposition = set.getFile(0);
DescriptorProto PositionEvent = geoposition.getMessageType(0);
```

Populate objects of protoc-generated domain classes, for testing:

```java
Meters horizAcc = Meters.newBuilder().setValue(4.9f).build();
PositionEvent pe = PositionEvent.newBuilder()
  .setPoint(point)
  .setTime(time)
  .setHorizontalAccuracy(horizAcc)
  ...
  .build();
```

Convert domain objects to byte arrays (simulating data on the wire):

```java
byte[] bytes = pe.toByteArray();
```

Convert byte arrays back to domain objects:

```java
PositionEvent pe2 = PositionEvent.newBuilder().mergeFrom(bytes).build();
```

The `mergeFrom` in the above lets me turn an array of bytes into an instance of a domain class which is generated prior to compile time. However, in the actual application, this generated class will not be available at compile time. I need to parse the message into an instance of a general-purpose class which will give me access to the values of individual fields in the message, and for message-valued fields, their fields, etc.

I think either `Descriptor` or `DescriptorProto` is the class I need to use, but the following does not seem to work:

```java
DescriptorProtos.DescriptorProto p = positionEvent.toBuilder().mergeFrom(bytes).build();
```

At least, I do not know how to retrieve the value for the "horizontal_accuracy" field in this `DescriptorProto` to determine that the value is `4.9`.

I can imagine a reflection-based solution in which, knowing **all** of the message types ahead of time, I use protoc to generate all of the domain classes, then I use reflection to populate an appropriate domain object for any given message, and step through its fields. However, this feels like a hack, and is not appropriate for scenarios in which there are hundreds or thousands of message types which change frequently (as is the case at my company).

Comment: Hi (from a fellow alum). Just curious, how were you "merging the byte array into various builders"? If you can edit your question to reveal some code for that.

Comment: Thanks, slackwing. I have added some example code to illustrate what I am trying to do. Also updated my profile :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you have so far is a `FileDescriptorProto`, which is the serialized, language-agnostic version of the descriptors. First you need to build its Java object from them, [`FileDescriptor` and `Descriptor`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.FileDescriptor.html). Take a look at the API to see how you'd use them to get a `Descriptor` for a specific type:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/path/to/mydescriptors.pb");
FileDescriptorSet set = FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(is);
FileDescriptorProto geopositionProto = set.getFile(0);

FileDescriptor geopositionDescriptor = FileDescriptor.buildFrom(
    set.getFile(0),
    set.getFileList().toArray(new FileDescriptor[0]));
Descriptor positionEventDescriptor = geopositionDescriptor.findMessageTypeByName("<package_name>.PositionEvent");
```

Then, [`DynamicMessage`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage) can be used to create and parse a proto object of an abstract type, given its descriptor (which you already have).

```
Message instance = DynamicMessage.parseFrom(positionEventDescriptor, bytes);
```

You can then use the reflection API (such as [`getAllFields()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder.html#getAllFields--)) to get the contents in a generic way.